How does basic style / method of argument differ in philosophy taught outside English-speaking world?
This is motivated by a comment I got here.
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/49364/which-languages-other-than-french-show-a-habit-of-trying-not-to-repeat-the-sam#comment117603_49364
In French, when you do expository writing, it is considered bad form to repeat a word too soon (i.e. within one sentence, or from one to the next).
I had known about this tendency by reading a lot of French. Until this comment, I was unaware that this is an explicit practice especially in universities.
I was bad at philosophy as an undergraduate, but I do recall a basic rule of essay-writing given to me (and probably most people reading this):
Be precise, instead of looking for synonyms to sound cool, because imprecision ruins the thought.
When philosophy is taught outside the Anglo-Saxon world, are the basic style and method of argument and ethos different? In what way are they different?
I (barely) know that Nietzsche and Foucault and Derrida etc. are very different from the philosophers I studied and had different interests. My question is about how you are told to think and write philosophically when you study it... which is somewhat captured by the ground rules that you might be given in an Introduction 101 class, if that helps concretise my question.
Cheers

In English, it can also be bad form to repeat a word too much. Although this is very context dependent, not a clear rule. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation

Considering a sort of "average", the two styles are quite different, but I think that "repetition" vs "synonyms" is the symptom and not the cause. Maybe what we have to deepen is analysis vs hermeneutics. Useful: Simon Critchley, Continental philosophy: A very short introduction (Oxford University Press, 2001)

3 quotes from Heidegger, a very non anglophine philosopher

I guess a problem with repeating words could be that you run the risk of muddying the waters as to their definition. So if you apply it as a catch all term it's hard for a reader to tell and communicate what it actually means, while if you describe a thing from different angles and by different names, it's more likely for a reader to grasp what you actually try to make them look at?

@causative I would get into trouble with my philosophy tutor if I engaged in elegant variation. The whole point of English-speaking philosophy is to keep to very fine distinctions between e.g. knowledge and awareness, concept and thought, if and iff, etc etc etc

There is a widely cited split between (very roughly) Anglophone and non-Anglophone philosophical traditions known as the analytic-continental divide. In Prado's description, "Analytic philosophers typically try to solve fairly delineated philosophical problems by reducing them to their parts and to the relations in which these parts stand. Continental philosophers typically address large questions in a synthetic or integrative way, and consider particular issues to be ‘parts of the larger unities’..."

@Conifold thanks I shall read the linked article. All I got from my tutors, in terms of any mention of continental philosophy (an option I didn't take) is an anecdote. A professor walked into the library and asked the librarian "What kinds of philosophy do the students like to study?" The librarian indicated Nietzsche. The professor was horrified that Nietzsche counted as philosophy.
